# Privoxy: forward & config.privoxy.org

Tags: proxy, privoxy

Privoxy allows forwarding requests though a remote proxy server using the configuration directive:

```
forward / remote_proxy_ip:remote_port
```

My problem is that requests to the local privoxy configuration page (http://config.privoxy.org) also seem to be forwarded.

I tried to create an exception to the forward with:

```
forward config.privoxy.org .
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Privoxy could not identify the local host name. Once one was provided in the config file, the configuration page showed up again. Note: issue was with version 3.0.9